# merge complex matrix with python

Tags: python, list

I have a complex matrix that looks like this:

```
[[ ['x', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
   ['y', '5', '6', '7', '8']],

 [ ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
   ['y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']  ] ]
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
['x', '1a', '2b', '3c', '4d'],
['y', '5e', '6f', '7g', '8h']
```

I'm busting my head but not managing to achieve the result. Also, even though I only have two groups of nested 5-items long lists, in theory I want to solve this for an infinite number of groups of the same size.

Comment: In the end, if all you want to do is manipulate complex number, there are better ways to do it.

Comment: in the end I want to translate this to javascript. I just hate js so I tried doing it in python first =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `dict` here:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> lis = [[ ['x', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
   ['y', '5', '6', '7', '8']],
 [ ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
   ['y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']  ] ]
>>> dic = {}
for item in lis:
    for x in item:
        k, v = x[0], x[1:]
        if k in dic:
            dic[k] = map(add, dic[k], v)
        else:
            dic[k] = v
...             
>>> dic
{'y': ['5e', '6f', '7g', '8h'], 'x': ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']}
#list of lists
>>> [[k] + v for k, v in dic.iteritems()]
[['y', '5e', '6f', '7g', '8h'], ['x', '1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']]
```

Another solution using `zip`, `reduce` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> def func(x, y):
...     return map(add, x, y[1:])

>>> [[item[0][0]] + reduce(func, item[1:], item[0][1:])  for item in zip(*lis)]
[['x', '1a', '2b', '3c', '4d'], ['y', '5e', '6f', '7g', '8h']]
```

Comment: in his case i believe 'x' is a value not a key same for 'y'

Comment: No no @drabo2005 this is the answer I was looking for. I was already headed in that direction, I just tried avoiding using a dictionary, but there's probably no better way

Comment: @yuvi I've added another solution, though it is not as readable as the first one.

Comment: Wow. Now that was what I was originally searching for, using zip and map and such, and avoiding using a dictionary altogether. Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "fun" solution. Since you did not provide any information about your array's structure, I assumed the easiest variant:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[
        ['x', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
        ['y', '5', '6', '7', '8']],
    [
        ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ['y', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]],
    dtype=numpy.object)

res = a[0].copy()
for chunk in a[1:]:
    res[:,1:] += chunk[:,1:]

print(res)
```

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful, but this time I actually needed a solution that doesn't use external libraries. I didn't mention that in the question, sorry about that. Gave you a 1+